# Non-taxable items in QBO API

Tags: c#, .net-core, quickbooks

I'm working on .NET Core API project and required to integrate QBO tax calculation inside my application. I've did the integration part and also able to create/edit Invoice/Estimate using the QBO API call. But currently I'm not able to pass non taxable items to the QBO. If I'm passing it is doing the tax calculation for all items.

Can some one knows how to pass non-taxable items in QBO API.

Here is the reference: [Manage Tax](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/workflows/manage-sales-tax-for-us-locales)